# Header page book in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer

How can I draw  this is  figure?

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[top=25mm,bottom=25mm,left=25mm,right=25mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[all]{background}

\usepackage{ptext,xcolor}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 

\usepackage{changepage}
\strictpagecheck


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{عنوان کتاب}
\fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1.2]{Yas} 
\linespread{1.5}

\newcommand*{\vsp}{2cm}
\newcommand*{\hsp}{2.5cm}

\newcommand{\MyTikzLogo}{% 
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\checkoddpage
\ifoddpage
    \draw  [color=magenta,line width=1mm] ($(\paperwidth+\hsp,-\vsp)$) --($(\hsp,-\vsp)$);
\else
    \draw  [color=cyan,line width=1mm] ($(0,-\vsp)$) --($(\paperwidth-\hsp,-\vsp)$);
\fi
 \end{tikzpicture}
}

\SetBgContents{\MyTikzLogo}
\SetBgPosition{current page.north west}
\SetBgOpacity{1.0}
\SetBgAngle{0.0}
\SetBgScale{1.0}

\begin{document}

\chapter{titel}

\section{sec }

\ptext[1-40]


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Here, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367145/using-tikz-in-the-header

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367145/using-tikz-in-the-header
This is my link. Unfortunately, I did not answer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would not use the background in this case. My proposal is to stick the decoration in the command that prints the page number, and use a `tikzpicture` with a controlled bounding box.

The following is a start --- I did only the upper part, the bottom one should be easier. I removed the Parsi things (I do not have the fonts).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[top=25mm,bottom=25mm,left=25mm,right=25mm,
    headheight=40pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shapes.geometric} 

\usepackage{changepage}
\strictpagecheck

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\myfancynum}
\fancyhead[LE]{book title}
\fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\linespread{1.5}

\newcommand{\myfancynum}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path (0,0) [use as bounding box]
        node[diamond, draw=cyan, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=32pt] (pageno) {\thepage} ;
    \checkoddpage\ifoddpage
    % 36pt = 32pt + 4pt +4pt; 
    \path (pageno.west) node[fill=cyan, fill opacity=0.4, diamond, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=16pt] {};
    \draw[cyan] (pageno.north) ++(0, +4pt) -- ++(40pt, -40pt) -- ++(\linewidth,0);
    \draw[cyan] (pageno.east) ++(4pt, 0) -- ++(-40pt, -40pt) -- ++(0, -4cm);
    \else
    \path (pageno.east) node[fill=cyan, fill opacity=0.4, diamond, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=16pt] {};
    \draw[cyan] (pageno.north) ++(0, +4pt) -- ++(-40pt, -40pt) -- ++(-\linewidth,0);
    \draw[cyan] (pageno.west) ++(-4pt, 0) -- ++(40pt, -40pt) -- ++(0, -4cm);
    \fi
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\section{A section}

\lipsum[1-40]

\end{document}
```

To obtain:

[image: Top of symmetric pages]

The trick here is the `use as bounding box` thing (you can use it in a `scope` if you need more thing) so that `fancyhdr` is convinced that the size of the picture is just the size of the diamond with the page number.

I had to increase the size of the header, obviously, too. The code should be cleaned upt to not to use all these constants, but hey, that's left as an exercise to the reader...

#### update with a new shape --- this shows the use of anchors, so it's quite educational, I think... changing:

```latex
\newcommand{\myfancynum}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % this trick is used to have the bounding box centered on the number, but
        % the real drawing (the star) hanging down (thanks to anchor=north).
        % By default, fancyhdr will line the baseline of this graph (that for it is
        % just the pagenumber) to the chapter-section-title whatever info it prints in
        % the header. 
        % To see how fancyhdr lines up things, change this \path to a \draw
        \path [use as bounding box] (-16pt,16pt) rectangle (16pt,-16pt);
            \path node[star, star points=8, star point ratio=1.3, draw=cyan,
                inner sep=0pt, minimum size=32pt, anchor=north] (pageno) {\thepage} ;
    \checkoddpage\ifoddpage
    % line lengths are adjusted by hand. Probably a bit of math could fix this, but well...
    \path (pageno.west) node[fill=cyan, fill opacity=0.4, diamond, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=16pt] {};
    \draw[cyan] (pageno.inner point 7) -- ++(44pt,0);
    \draw[cyan] (pageno.east) -- ++(+40pt, 0) -- ++(4pt,-4pt) -- ++({\linewidth-48pt},0);
    \draw[cyan] (pageno.outer point 6) -- ++(\linewidth,0);
    \draw[cyan] (pageno.west) -- ++(-8pt, -8pt) -- ++(0, -4cm);
    \else
    \path (pageno.east) node[fill=cyan, fill opacity=0.4, diamond, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=16pt] {};
    \draw[cyan] (pageno.inner point 2) -- ++(-44pt,0);
    \draw[cyan] (pageno.west) -- ++(-40pt, 0) -- ++(-4pt,-4pt) -- ++({-\linewidth+48pt},0);
    \draw[cyan] (pageno.outer point 4) -- ++(-\linewidth,0);
    \draw[cyan] (pageno.east) -- ++(+8pt, -8pt) -- ++(0, -4cm);
    \fi
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

will give you:

[image]

Comment: +1: Really impressive what tikz can achieve with a few lines of code. Thank you for sharing!

Comment: +1 also for me :-)