# Adding coloured margins to the pages

Tags: margins

Is it possible to add a colored margin to the pages according to the example below with having the chapter title written on the side (alternatively, it could say "Ch.1: Heading on level  (chapter)") and the section title written on top (alternatively, it could say "1.1 Heading on level 1 (section)" and "1.2 Lists") as well as the page number at the bottom of the colored area (near the middle of the page).

And I would like to have every chapter with a different color.

The width of the margin will have to be customized manually I guess but 1cm should be fine.

I am using the book document class: \documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}

[image]

What I have so far would be the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in}, left=1.5in, top=0.5in, includeheadfoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! The drawing is different, but what about [the idea here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367158/header-page-book-in-tikz) ?

Comment: Moreover, if you can add a complete, compilable code with what you tried, people can use that to help you achieve the final result. Please help us to help you; otherwise we will have to do all the work of preparing an example document from scratch.

Comment: I've edited my post to add a MWE but as you can see, I didn't go really far. The idea you suggested goes to the right direction and I saw it previously but it still doesn't really do what I would like. I tried to play around with it but without success. I also found [this other post](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=12843) which goes to the right direction as well and tried to combine them but again without success.

Comment: I think here there are some useful ideas about detecting even and odd pages: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6143/if-then-else-for-odd-page-even-page
And at the end there is something similar to your drawing. 
For changing the color, you could simply define a custom color and re-define it before `\chapter` command