# Is it possible to add a large image with page number at the corner in the header?

Tags: header-footer

As described in the title. What I'm trying to design is this:
[image]

This screenshot is from my .docx document. I have extracted the upper-right image. However, when I'm trying to define the header, I got a very bad result.

[image]

If I keep increasing the image size, the header will overlap with the main text. And, I have completely no idea how to add the page number on it.

Could anyone let me know what I should do in this case? The tex file content is:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  margin=1in,
  headsep=18pt, % separation between header rule and text
]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand{\statement}[1]{\medskip\noindent
  \textcolor{black}{\textbf{#1}}\space
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{
\textcolor{gray}{Name}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize\thepage}
\rhead{\textcolor{gray}{Institution}\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{header.png}}
\let\oldcenter\center
\let\oldendcenter\endcenter
\renewenvironment{center}{\setlength\topsep{0pt}\oldcenter}{\oldendcenter}

\newcommand{\wordcount}{
\begin{center}
\rule{0.75\textwidth}{.4pt}\\
{\footnotesize A statement of \numwords \ words}
\end{center}
}

\newif\ifcomments

\newcommand{\comment}[1]{}
\newcommand{\todo}[1]{\ifcomments\textcolor{red}{TODO: #1}\fi}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Edit this section %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\commentstrue

\newcommand{\soptitle}{Statement of Purpose}
\newcommand{\yourname}{My Name}
\newcommand{\yourintent}{Applicant for a PhD in The Thing}
\newcommand{\school}{The University}
\newcommand{\advisorfirstname}{FirstName}
\newcommand{\advisorlastname}{LastName}
\newcommand{\advisorfull}{Prof. \advisorfirstname \ \advisorlastname}
\newcommand{\advisor}{Prof. \advisorlastname}
\newcommand{\numwords}{\todo{number}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[
  breaklinks,
  pdftitle={\yourname - \soptitle},
  pdfauthor={\yourname},
  unicode,
  colorlinks,
  urlcolor={blue!80!black}
]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\statement{Introduction} I want to work with \advisorfull. \advisor \ is good. \href{https://www.google.com}{Here} is my website.\footnote{Footnote}
\wordcount

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to hide the picture size. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367158/header-page-book-in-tikz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You effectively want to place both the corner image and the page number using a more absolute placement technique. One such option is to use [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic). You can place the corner image first, then the page number, all in the background of the page.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  margin=1in,
  headsep=18pt, % separation between header rule and text
]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyhead[L]{\textcolor{gray}{Name}}
\fancyhead[R]{\textcolor{gray}{Institution}}

\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
  % Place corner image in background of all pages
  \AtPageUpperLeft{% Move to upper left corner
    \raisebox{-\height}{% Drop content by its entire height, so it is placed on the page
      \makebox[\paperwidth][r]{% Push corner to the right of the page
        \includegraphics{corner}% Insert corner image
      }%
    }%
  }%
  % Add page number on top of corner image
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height-2\baselineskip}{% Drop lower on page
      \makebox[\paperwidth][r]{%
        \textcolor{white}{\bfseries\thepage}%
        \hspace{2em}% Push away from right margin
      }%
    }%
  }%
}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

`\AddToShipoutPictureBG` adds content to the `B`ack`G`round of all subsequent pages. Then, `eso-pic` provides some supplementary placement macros, like `\AtPageUpperLeft`, which puts the content at the upper left corner of the page. Since you want it at the upper right corner, we move it over using a box (`\makebox[\paperwidth][r]`) and lower it within view (via `\raisebox{-\height}`). In a similar way you can place the page number.

Since this forms part of the shipout procedure, `\thepage` will be an accurate representation of the page number.

With the header now separate from the corner image/page number, you can manage them without interference.

Comment: Belated congrats on passing the 600k rep mark!